# Using bing to geocode

Tags: c#-4.0, coordinates, bing, geocode

I'm trying to find out how to use bing to get lat/long. All the tutorials I find are for plotting points but don't actually show how to extract the coordinates. Anyone have experience with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the new way to do that is by using their REST service documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701715.aspx.

For example:

> [http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?key=BingMapsKey&query=White
>   House](http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?key=BingMapsKey&query=White%20House)
>     or
>   [http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?key=BingMapsKey&query=1600
>   Pennsylvania Ave NW Washington, DC](http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?key=BingMapsKey&query=1600%20Pennsylvania%20Ave%20NW%20Washington,%20DC)

Answer (score 1):

We use the [VEMap.Geocode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff710027.aspx) method and it works just great.

see [Bing Maps Ajax Control v6.3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429619.aspx)